# wonderlands.com annoying pop-up redirects

Tags: windows, windows-10, virus, rundll32.exe

### Dear moderators

This question is not a duplicate, as it is about a special case, not a general question. please open this up and let the problem be solved, as this relates to so many people. you may find the view count intresting

### Problem

As for [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/128957/removal-of-the-wonderlandads-com-pop-up-virus) or [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/129057/why-does-chrome-open-links-from-wonderlandads-com-on-scrolling) or even [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33734490/chrome-opens-wonderlands-link-on-scrolling), my computer has been infected to this sh-t and my browsers open an annoying pop-up ( http://wonderlandads.com/afu.php?zoneid=437742 ) on every single click to whatever web page I am visiting and this is repeated really unlimited times, getting me more and more nervous.

It was just Google Chrome ( 47.0.2526.106 m ), but now I have it on Opera ( 34.0.2036.25 ) too, and I think it will go through the Firefox, IE, ... soon.

### Environment

- Windows 10 x64 Enterprise (1151) Build 10586.29

### My efforts

- I found [this link](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chrome/xQmC0-iA5jQ/bkt5c-NZCQAJ) which would be useful.
- Used Chrome's `Help > Report and issue` menu to report it to the Google.
- Used the [Chrome Cleanup Tool](https://www.google.com/chrome/cleanup-tool/) to remove any problems at the very first moment (just before my opera get infected too).
- Using the tool, I noticed that the `exe` file ( Chrome Cleanup Tool ) gets deleted automatically right after usage and so I added an audit on the file for deletion to suspect what process deletes the `chrome_cleanup_tool.exe` file using `Security` section under `Windows Logs` in `Windows Even Viewr`. The answer was:

  ```
  Object:
      Object Server:          Security
      Object Type:            File
      Object Name:            C:\Users\{my-user-name}\Downloads\chrome_cleanup_tool.exe
      Handle ID:              0x2c
      Resource Attributes:    S:AI

  Process Information:
      Process ID:             0x179c
      Process Name:           C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rundll32.exe

  Access Request Information:
      Accesses:               DELETE
      Access Mask:            0x10000
  ```

  So I am almost sure that my windows has been infected with virus and there is nothing to do with Chrome, Opera, ...

### My question

- How can I remove the infection from my computer?
- Any suggestions or similar efforts would be appreciated.

Comment: You got a backup?

Comment: backup of what?

Comment: @Tetsujin has it right.  Read the link provided.  This is not a special case.  It sounds like a bog-standard virus that will take bog-standard removal approaches.  Ie, if you think you're good enough, pull out a Live-CD and do it that way, otherwise be prepared to reinstall everything.  Based on your 'backup of what?' response to Jamie's comment, I'd go with a reinstallation (backup of your data, downloads, other content, etc, btw).